# how to add subdomain using route53 and godaddy

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, nameserver, amazon-s3, dig

## background

I've already added a zone for an S3 bucket to host my static site (pointing to lobolabshq.com), now I wanted to do the same for mattermost.lobolabshq.com)

I followed the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html) and added an A record for mattermost.lobolabshq.com, which worked just fine when I run the dig command and specify the name server of AWS:

```
 dig @ns-491.awsdns-61.com mattermost.lobolabshq.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @ns-491.awsdns-61.com mattermost.lobolabshq.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55671
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mattermost.lobolabshq.com. IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mattermost.lobolabshq.com. 300  IN  A   54.227.230.157

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mattermost.lobolabshq.com. 172800 IN    NS  ns-1300.awsdns-34.org.
mattermost.lobolabshq.com. 172800 IN    NS  ns-2001.awsdns-58.co.uk.
mattermost.lobolabshq.com. 172800 IN    NS  ns-491.awsdns-61.com.
mattermost.lobolabshq.com. 172800 IN    NS  ns-795.awsdns-35.net.

;; Query time: 143 msec
;; SERVER: 205.251.193.235#53(205.251.193.235)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb  2 12:02:21 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 196
```

## problem

[This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html) is the part I'm not sure about:

> Using the method provided by the DNS service of the parent domain, add
>   NS records for the subdomain to the zone file for the parent domain.
>   In these NS records, specify the four Amazon Route 53 name servers
>   that are associated with the hosted zone that you created in Step 1.

I'm not sure how to do that in godaddy console.. so what I did is that I simply added 4 NS (nameserver) records in my godaddy and pointed them to the said aws nameservers like so:

[image]

but when I dig mattermost.lobolabshq.com I get nothing (although I did this change more than an hour ago, and the TTL for the NSServers specifically says 1 hour):

```
 dig  mattermost.lobolabshq.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> mattermost.lobolabshq.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 41327
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mattermost.lobolabshq.com. IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
lobolabshq.com.     501 IN  SOA ns-558.awsdns-05.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 49 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.43.1#53(192.168.43.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb  2 12:02:39 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 124
```

Is this just a matter of waiting or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions you followed are for [Creating a Subdomain That Uses Amazon Route 53 as the DNS Service **without Migrating the Parent Domain**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html).

That's not what you're doing, here. The phrase "without migrating the parent domain" refers to migrating the *DNS hosting* for the parent domain -- not the *registrar* service.

```
$ dig @a.root-servers.net lobolabshq.com ns +trace
--8<-- snip --8<--
lobolabshq.com.         172800  IN      NS      ns-1218.awsdns-24.org.
lobolabshq.com.         172800  IN      NS      ns-1754.awsdns-27.co.uk.
lobolabshq.com.         172800  IN      NS      ns-558.awsdns-05.net.
lobolabshq.com.         172800  IN      NS      ns-57.awsdns-07.com.
```

The parent domain's DNS is already hosted at Route 53, so these directions aren't applicable.

All you need to do is create an A-record called "mattermost" inside the existing "lobolabshq.com" Route 53 Hosted Zone (the one that uses the 4 nameservers shown above) and configure it as desired.

The NS resource records you added to the DNS hosting panel at Go Daddy are not actually doing anything -- nothing you do in that particular screen is going to do anything, because even though Go Daddy is your registrar, their DNS servers are no longer authoritative for your domain.  DNS hosting and registrar are services that any providers bundle together, but they are actually two different things.